# JPA entity classes generator from liquibase config

Tags: spring, jpa, liquibase

We are planning to use liquibase as our database scripts automation tool for maintain and applying ddl and dml.

Is there any library which can read the ddl defined in liquibase config and generate jpa entity java class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liquibase is version management and database initialization tool.It created entity and relations.If you want classes to be created automatically, you can use JHipster Domain Language.
[Jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/)

Comment: Thanks! In my case I need to auto generate repo class and a bao dao class with minimal solution.

Comment: I read the link you shared jhipster and it seems to be good option as well. Due to the time constraints and the customization required for our application I am not consider jhipster now .

Comment: Today I got a chance to explore and it worked like magic! I really liked and I am going to explore this tool more. Thanks for sharing.